# Kernel estimation using one bandwidth value per point

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm familiar with the usual Kernel density estimation (KDE) where a single bandwidth value is used to generate a multivariate (usually Gaussian) function for each sample point. The final KDE is then obtained by summing the Gaussian functions for all the sample points.

Say I have N sample points (assume in 1 dimension) each one with an error estimate, e.g.:

```
sample_points = [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 1.2, 0.01, 3.6, 0.4]
errors = [0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01, 0.07]
```

What I'm after, is a way to obtain the KDE for this sample using the error associated to each point as the bandwidth for its function.

I could eventually do this by manually obtaining the Gaussian kernel for each point separately, and then combining all the functions (no easy task).

Is there an already implemented function that does this? I've looked around but the kernel density estimator functions I found ([scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), [sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity)) use a fixed bandwidth value for all the points.

Answer (score 3):

I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160012/kde-in-python-with-different-mu-sigma-mapping-a-function-to-an-array). There are (as far I was able to find) no implementations of that. Here is what I used (which works for my needs):

```
import numpy as np

def solve_gaussian(val,data_array,sigma_array):
    return (1. / sigma_array) * np.exp(- (val - data_array) * (val - data_array) / (2 * sigma_array * sigma_array))

def solve_kde(xlist,data_array,sigma_array):
    kde_array = np.array([])
    for xx in xlist:
        single_kde = solve_gaussian(xx,data_array,sigma_array)
        if np.ndim(kde_array) == 3:
            kde_array = np.concatenate((kde_array,single_kde[np.newaxis,:,:]),axis=0)
        else:
            kde_array = np.dstack(single_kde)
    return kde_array

xlist = np.linspace(0,1,101) #Adjust as needed
kde_array = solve_kde(xlist,data_array,sigma_array)
kde_vector = np.sum(np.sum(kde_array,axis=2),axis=1)
mode_guess = xlist[np.argmax(kde_vector)]
```

It's a reimplementation of the scipy gaussian kde.

Comment: (I must've missed this answer a year ago, sorry) I commented on your other answer presenting this code, I'll do it here too for completeness. Shouldn't the `sigma_array` *divide* the exponential rather than multiplying it, i.e.: `(1./sigma_array) * np.exp(- (val - data_array) *...`?

Comment: As in the other answer, yes; both have been fixed. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: How do you store data in `data_array` and `sigma_array`? I'm getting some errors trying to feed data to `solve_kde`. Also, is your code supposed to work for multiple dimensions?